# I getting this error 'Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child' even if I used Array of objects what to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`

```
const fashionCardData = [
  { id: "1", src: "1.png" },
  { id: "2", src: "2.png" },
  { id: "4", src: "4.png" },
];

const Products = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {fashionCardData.map((item)=>{
        <img key={item.id} src={`images/${item.src}`} alt={item.id}/>
      })}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

`

I am trying to map an array but it doesn't work please help

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
{fashionCardData.map((item)=>{
    <img key={item.id} src={`images/${item.src}`} alt={item.id}/>
  })}
```

with

```
{fashionCardData.map((item)=>(
    <img key={item.id} src={`images/${item.src}`} alt={item.id}/>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are not returning the component.

Change your code to

```
{fashionCardData.map((item)=>{
    return (<img key={item.id} src={`images/${item.src}`} alt={item.id}/>);
  })}
```

Code that is inside `{}` will be treated as javascript and similarly code that is inside `()` will be treated as jsx.